# How to sum up the data for the overlapped data in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, overlap, date-range

I have the data like below:

```
t_id s_id   date_1      date_2      T_count            expected Result
N1  1-1I    2012-12-11  2013-01-22  0.21327014218009478622 4.7
N2  1-1I    2011-08-03  2011-11-10  3.8461538461538462     4.7
N3  1-1I    2013-12-05  2013-12-20  1.6935483870967742     4.7
N4  1-1I    2014-12-08  2015-06-25  4.7727272727272727     4.7
N5  1-1I    2017-03-08  (null)      (null)                 4.7
N6  1-I6    2013-04-11  2013-10-03  0.61538461538461538462 0.97
N7  1-I6    2011-09-27  2013-06-20  0.37325038880248833651 0.97
```

AND I want to calculate sum of the t_count value if date1 and date2 of same s_id overlaps with the same s_id for different t_id else return maximum value for the same s_id.

Right now the postgres code i am using is doing sum of the values irrespective of overlap, please could you suggest.

There might be cases where some data overlap and some don't for a given s_id, so for the years it overlap, we need to some that up and find the maximum of the all the cases like individual, overlapped and give one answer which is maximum of all.

```
select t1.s_id,sum(t1.t_count) 
              from abc t1
              JOIN abc t2
              ON daterange(t1.date_1, t1.date_2, '[]')
                             && daterange(t1.date_1, t1.date_2, '[]')
                                      and t1.s_id = t2.s_id
              GROUP BY t1.s_id
```

Comment: you should join on s_id only and check if overlaps in `case when` - but I dont understand why you build daterange on t1 dates only - what should overlap with what?.. Or its just a typo?..

Comment: And what should be the result if only some intervals for a certain `s_id` overlap? For example, if you change `date_1` for `N3` to `2013-01-05`, what would be the result?

Comment: Have a look at this answer https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/89864/maximum-sum-of-overlapping-ranges

Comment: How did you get expected result `1.97`? `0.62 + 0.37` is `0.99`.

Comment: @vladimir: my fault..i was creating sample data so mistakenly did that bit

Comment: @user3222101, there is a good article [Packing Intervals
by Itzik Ben-Gan](http://blogs.solidq.com/en/sqlserver/packing-intervals) which seems to be relevant after your clarifications in the question. It is written for SQL Server, but Postgres has all the necessary features as well. Obviously, Postgres may have some specific temporal features that may make the query more efficient, but I still think that this article is worth a look.

Comment: sure thanks vladimir !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was doing the mistake of comparing with itself, i modified code a bit to get this result.

```
with cte as
(

    select t1.s_id,sum(t1.t_count) as scount
                  from abc t1
                  JOIN abc t2
                  ON daterange(t1.date_1, t1.date_2, '[]')
                                 && daterange(t1.date_1, t1.date_2, '[]')
                                          and t1.s_id = t2.s_id
                  and t1.s_id ! = t2.s_id
                  GROUP BY t1.s_id
) 
select 
      s_id,greatest(scount,max(t_count) over (partition by s_id)) as finalvalue 
from abc 
left outer join cte 
on abc.s_id = cte.s_id
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear how the logic should work if some of the intervals of a certain `s_id` overlap and some don't.

If you know that in your data either all intervals overlap, or none overlap, then it is easy to determine it.

Calculate duration of each interval and sum up all these durations. Compare it to the duration from the first to the last date.

I assume that `NULL` in `date_2` means some really large date in the future.

```
WITH
CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        s_id
        ,SUM(COALESCE(date_2, '9999-12-31') - date_1) AS TotalDuration
        ,MIN(date_1) AS FirstDate
        ,MAX(COALESCE(date_2, '9999-12-31')) AS LastDate
        ,SUM(T_count) AS SumCount
        ,MAX(T_count) AS MaxCount
    FROM YourTable
    GROUP BY s_id
)
SELECT
    s_id
    ,CASE WHEN TotalDuration > (LastDate - FirstDate)
    THEN -- intervals overlap
        SumCount
    ELSE -- none of the intervals overlap
        MaxCount
    END AS Result
FROM CTE
;
```